# Basic histogram in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, histogram

I need to create a simple histogram using JFreeChart. There should be 3 groups with numeric values assigned to each of these groups. The problem is that `DefaultCategoryDataset` requires specifying "Group" and "Subgroup" (i.e. `dataset.setValue(5,"Subgroup1.1","Group1"`);), but I don´t have subgroups. What is the alternative of `DefaultCategoryDataset`? I need to get something like this:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.setValue(2, "Group1");
dataset.setValue(3, "Group2");
dataset.setValue(5, "Group3");
```

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. An example is given here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYSeriesDemo3.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the same row key for each bin and vary the column key, like this:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(561, "Age", "1 - 10");
dataset.addValue(1231, "Age", "10 - 20");
dataset.addValue(12323, "Age", "20+");
```